# javascript adding a resize function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add a resize function so I can check and then apply classes on window resize.
I can't use media-query so I have to achieve using javascript.

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 640px)" );
var el = document.getElementById('output');

if (mq.matches) {
  el.innerHTML ='640 and over';
  el.className += 'over'
} else {
  el.innerHTML ='640 and under';
  el.className += 'under'
}
```

```css
#output{
  padding:20px;
  color:#fff;
}

.over{
  background:#808;
}

.under{
  background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Curious why you can't use media-queriies?  Are you saying you can't use an external library?

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: @user3699998, are you asking for JavaScript code that detects the browser window's size on resize?

Comment: Please see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('output');
function checkSize() {

   if(window.innerWidth >= 640) {
      el.innerHTML = '640 and over';
      el.className = 'over'
   } else {
     el.innerHTML = 'under 640';
     el.className = 'under'
   }

 }
 window.addEventListener("resize", checkSize)
 checkSize()
```

```css
#output{
  padding:20px;
  color:#fff;
}

.over{
  background:#808;
}

.under{
  background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: @user3699998 sure, sorry. had a mistake